# Creating an account in ejabberd

Tags: c#, ios, ejabberd

I am tring to create a chat application for ios. I am using the ejabberd server for that. I have successfully installed ejabberd in my windows dedicated server from [here](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/archive/). I tried logging into in using XMPP clients and it was successful. Now I can assume that the ejabberd is up and running in my server.

Now I want to create/register a new user with ejabberd in my server. I can do it using the web interface provided by ejabberd. But how can I do the same using asp.net c# from the same server?

How can I create a new account in ejabberd using c#?

Answer (score 0):

You can talk to ejabberd using xmlrpc, check

https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/ejabberd_xmlrpc

Answer (score 0):

You can using Ejabberd administration API. Your API address should be  http://domain:5443/api
And you can find more detail about Ejabberd API, here : https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/